# Can I use the ng-if on a ng-repeater?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and was wondering how to tackle the following situation.  I'm using angular with jquery mobile and am creating a one page app.  When the app loads, I have it create pages or divs inside the body tag.  I have two types of pages, "typical pages" and "video pages" but I want to use one object to create both page types.  I want to use one object because I also use that object to create my menu and I don't want to have to edit multiple objects.

My issue is, I want to create a "typical page" for each element in the object but I only want to create a "video page" for each object that doesn't have "videoPage: false".  I tried using ng-if on the "video page" ng-repeater (see html below) but it doesn't seem to be working.  Can I use the ng-if on a ng-repeater?

I have the following data/object:

```
function App($scope){
    $scope.pages = [
        {
            id: "intro",
            title: "Intro",
            videoPage: false
        },{
            id: "activeStretches",
            title: "Active Stretches by Area"
        },{
            id: "passiveStretches",
            title: "Passive Stretches by Area"
        }
    ];
}
```

And the html:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="App">

    <div data-role="page" id="{{page.id}}" ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="h">
            <a data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
            <h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-side">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li ng-repeat="menu in pages" data-theme="{{menu.title == page.title && 'h'}}">
                        <a href="{{menu.id}}" class="{{menu.class}}">{{menu.title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                Typical Page
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="{{page.id}}Video" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-if="page.videoPage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="h">
            <a data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
            <h1 class="vidTitle"></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-side">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li ng-repeat="menu in pages" data-theme="{{menu.title == page.title && 'h'}}">
                        <a href="{{menu.id}}" class="{{menu.class}}">{{menu.title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                Video Page
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?  ng-if is new as of 1.1.5  (moved this to an answer in case other's experience the same problem)

Comment: Good call.  Looks like I'm using AngularJS v1.0.8.  I'll get the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-if is new as of 1.1.15 so make sure you're using a new (currently unstable) version of Angular.

And, yes, you can mix ng-if with ng-repeat.  Here's a fiddle showing it in action (using 1.2): http://jsfiddle.net/rbQry/1/

Note this line (switch the ng-if to "true" and the repeat comes back):

```
   <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query" ng-if="false">
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue.  I had downloaded the "stable" version.  I downloaded 1.2 and it works great now.  Thanks!